# Setting volumes in docker-compose within Vagrant

Tags: docker, docker-compose, vagrant

I'm trying to make use of the built-in docker-compose provider support in Vagrant (not the provisioner or the extension here: https://github.com/leighmcculloch/vagrant-docker-compose)

As I understand it the vagrant provider configuration is merged with the compose_configuration to generate the docker-compose.yml, which is then executed by docker-compose.

But it seems like some features in docker-compose cannot be specified in the vagrant configuration, for example named volumes. If I have this:

```
config.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
  d.build_dir = "." 
  d.has_ssh = true
  d.compose = true
  d.volumes = ["~/web:/web-host"]
  d.compose_configuration = {
      "version" => '2', 
      "services" => {
            "default" => {
                "volumes" => [
                  "dragonfly:~/public/dragonfly" ]
             }
      }
  }
```

}

I would expect vagrant to merge the two volumes, but instead it just seems to overwrite the compose_configuration one in the generated docker-compose.yml so I end up with:

```
default:
  volumes:
    - "~/web:/vagrant"
```

I've no idea where the /vagrant path is coming from.

And docker named volumes cannot be set in the main vagrant config as they are not supported.

So where should I be setting the volumes so they are carried through into docker-compose ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use docker-compose for container-host folder syncing purposes only? I was actually trying to do so; that's how I got to this post in the first place.

If that's the case, you could simply use the Vagrant `config.vm.synced_folder` property in your `Vagrantfile`, as specified [here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vagrant/docs/synced-folders/basic_usage).

This is an example of a `Vagrantfile` that uses Docker as a provider and syncs some host folder with a Docker container folder:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.synced_folder "host/folder", "/container/folder"
  config.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
    # Docker configuration options go here
  end
end
```

`host/folder` can be absolute or relative (to your project root) path. `/container/folder` must always be an absolute path. Please check the aforementioned documentation for further details on this matter.

Regarding your doubt about the `/vagrant` path: Vagrant syncs your project folder at your host machine with the container's `/vagrant` folder by default. If you want to disable this syncing, you need to specify the following line at your `Vagrantfile`:

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
```

Most likely you have figured out a solution to your problem a long time ago, but just thought this answer could help you or others :-).